# GetStream API Error: To target payload is incomplete (missing signature)

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to use GetStream API to post activities in timelines.

It works fine if I post in a single timeline. For example:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Stream-Auth-Type: jwt" -H "Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhY3Rpb24iOiJ3cml0ZSIsImZlZWRfaWQiOiJ1c2VyMSIsInJlc291cmNlIjoiZmVlZCJ9.r0zd_F0ujWKnNMCLiKVeZbfruy6-..." -d "{\"actor\": \"user:1\",\"verb\": \"status\",\"object\": \"1\",\"user\": {\"display_name\": \"Administrator\",\"first_name\": \"golflink1\",\"last_name\": \"Administrator\",\"gender\": \"Female\",\"profile_pic_thumb_url\": \"\"},\"course\": {\"course_id\": 879,\"course_name\": \"Admiral Baker, North\",\"city\": \"San Diego\",\"state_name\": \"California\",\"banner_image_url\": \"/ui/images/courses/golfcourse_detail.jpg\"},\"status\": \"sample string 1\"}" https://api.stream-io-api.com/api/v1.0/feed/user/1/?api_key=...
```

but I get following error when I try to post an event in multiple timelines using **"To"** field (using same token):

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Stream-Auth-Type: jwt" -H "Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhY3Rpb24iOiJ3cml0ZSIsImZlZWRfaWQiOiJ1c2VyMSIsInJlc291cmNlIjoiZmVlZCJ9.r0zd_F0ujWKnNMCLiKVeZbfruy6-..." -d "{\"actor\": \"user:1\",\"verb\": \"status\",\"object\": \"1\"**,\"to\": [\"timeline:global\",\"course:879\",\"city:US_CA_San_Diego\"]**,\"user\": {\"display_name\": \"Administrator\",\"first_name\": \"golflink1\",\"last_name\": \"Administrator\",\"gender\": \"Female\",\"profile_pic_thumb_url\": \"\"},\"course\": {\"course_id\": 879,\"course_name\": \"Admiral Baker, North\",\"city\": \"San Diego\",\"state_name\": \"California\",\"banner_image_url\": \"/ui/images/courses/golfcourse_detail.jpg\"},\"status\": \"sample string 1\"}" https://api.stream-io-api.com/api/v1.0/feed/user/1/?api_key=...

**Response Error:**

```
{"code": 4, "detail": "To target payload is incomplete (missing signature)", "duration": "14ms", "exception": "InputException", "status_code": 400}
```

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using? Depending on the language, there will be an API client available. You can get a token/signature for the corresponding feed in the "to" array and add it like so:

```
feed = client.feed(slug, id);

// instead of the feed id, give the feed id and the token an a sub-array
to = [
    [feed.id, feed.token],
];

// or concatenate the id and the token with a space:
to = [
    feed.id + ' ' + feed.token
];
```

(pseudo code, but all API clients have similar methods)

Comment: I am sending HTTP/CURL request from ASP.Net code. 

I tried it the way, you suggested but now I get following error:

    {"code": 4, "detail": "Errors for fields 'to'", "duration": "10ms", "exception": "InputException", "exception_fields": {"to": [{"0": ["Invalid value."], "1": ["Invalid value."], "2": ["Invalid value."]}]}, "status_code": 400}

Sample Request:

    {
  "actor": "user:1",
  "verb": "status",
  "object": "1",
  "to": [
    "timeline:global ey...to",
    "course:879 ey...1M",
    "city:US_CA_San_Diego ey...1I"
  ],
  ...
}

Comment: Hi Raman. That token looks incorrect. I believe you're using ReadOnlyToken (which is a JWT token) but it should be the other one, if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: I intentionally posted incomplete token.
Full e.g. "course:879 eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhY3Rpb24iOiJ3cml0ZSIsImZlZWRfaWQiOiJjb3Vyc2U4NzkiLCJyZXNvdXJjZSI6ImZlZWQifQ.rwGDoLZ03DT2_3-qHzEfupYoprqKHguxsNsnXbhhDTw eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhY3Rpb24iOiJ3cml0ZSIsImZlZWRfaWQiOiJjb3Vyc2U4NzkgZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LmV5SmhZM1JwYjI0aU9pSjNjbWwwWlNJc0ltWmxaV1JmYVdRaU9pSmpiM1Z5YzJVNE56a2lMQ0p5WlhOdmRYSmpaU0k2SW1abFpXUWlmUS5yd0dEb0xaMDNEVDJfMy1xSHpFZnVwWW9wcnFLSGd1eHNOc25YYmhoRFR3IiwicmVzb3VyY2UiOiJmZWVkIn0.0gMm_dTRFsDOpiiVCPtU4dH0AcwE2udeumTA321Qo1M",

Comment: Hi, yes, the start of the token `ey` gave it away already. That's a base64 encoded json string. You need the other token, not the read only one.